# Do we need the 'gmail-synchronization' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed that we apparently have a [gmail-synchronization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-synchronization) tag, and I'm considering deleting it and retagging the ~20 questions currently using it. It seems to me that there is no need for this tag as any questions can be adequately covered by simply using [gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) and [sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) in tandem, rather than creating a compound tag for this, which is something of an anomaly at the moment (i.e. do we create tags like this for every sync-able data feature?).

However, I'm also a little concerned that perhaps there is something unique about the way Gmail syncs it's data which I am perhaps not aware of, so I wanted to pose this question before doing anything. Is there a reasonable use for this tag that I am overlooking, which the other two do not fulfill? Should this tag be kept?

Comment: I think gmail and sync separately would be fine. I don't think there is anything special about gmail-sync (it just syncs with the cloud... nothing special about it).

Comment: Yeah the only thing unique is how often it screws up :P.  Your proposal sounds fine to me.

Comment: Heh! I suppose am to blame for editing the gmail-synchronization tag :P But yeah, there is a lot of tags in there that has no descriptions or has 0 followers (am seeing some on SO, and some are not even needed...) and duly reject them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be the sort of tag that someone would follow. I don't know of anything that's really all that unique about Gmail's sync that wouldn't just be covered by [gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail).